# non-finite finite difference error still exists even using mle2

Tags: r, mle

To whom it may concern,

I ran MLE analyses on individual dataset of a binary choice task (each dataset includes several trials in which the certain subject needs to choose option A or B) via R. First I tried optim (method=BFGS). For some individuals, I cannot get the parameter estimates due to the "non-finite finite difference error". I searched online and found that the bbmle toolbox can handel this error by providing "the option of inverting the Hessian Matrix" during calculation. However, the error still appearred even when I adopted the mle2 function and set the "skip.hessian=T". I know there might be some other solotions such as changing the initial guess; however, it's really annoying that sometimes the updated initial guess works for this subject but doesn't work for the other subject.
   Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem in mle2? I'm looking forward to your reply. Thanks and have a nice day :-)

Best,
Yang

Sorry for not providing testdata as I don't have online-drive. You're welcome to get the testdata via email (huyang@uni-bonn.de)

My code are the following:

```
##############################################################
###    Step 1: Define the Log-likelihood Function of M1    ###
##############################################################

logl <- function(alpha,beta,delta1,delta2,delta3,epsilon){
  data<-df_sbj
  y <- data$Y
  s1 <- data$s1
  o1 <- data$o1
  s2 <- data$s2
  o2 <- data$o2
  adv1<- ifelse(data$s1>data$o1,c(data$s1-data$o1),c(0))
  adv2<- ifelse(data$s2>data$o2,c(data$s2-data$o2),c(0))
  disadv1<- ifelse(data$o1>data$s1,c(data$o1-data$s1),c(0))
  disadv2<- ifelse(data$o2>data$s2,c(data$o2-data$s2),c(0))
  u1<-vector()
  u2<-vector()
  for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if (data$f1[j]=="human" & data$f2[j]=="greedy"){
      u1[j]<-s1[j]-alpha*disadv1[j]-beta*adv1[j]+delta1*adv1[j]-delta1*disadv1[j]
      u2[j]<-s2[j]-alpha*disadv2[j]-beta*adv2[j]+delta1*adv2[j]-delta1*disadv2[j]
    } else if (data$f1[j]=="human" & data$f2[j]=="equal") {
      u1[j]<-s1[j]-alpha*disadv1[j]-beta*adv1[j]-delta2*adv1[j]+delta2*disadv1[j]
      u2[j]<-s2[j]-alpha*disadv2[j]-beta*adv2[j]-delta2*adv2[j]+delta2*disadv2[j]
    } else if (data$f1[j]=="human" & data$f2[j]=="generous") {
      u1[j]<-s1[j]-alpha*disadv1[j]-beta*adv1[j]-delta3*adv1[j]+delta3*disadv1[j]
      u2[j]<-s2[j]-alpha*disadv2[j]-beta*adv2[j]-delta3*adv2[j]+delta3*disadv2[j]
    } else {
      u1[j]<-s1[j]-alpha*disadv1[j]-beta*adv1[j]
      u2[j]<-s2[j]-alpha*disadv2[j]-beta*adv2[j]
    }

  }
  #u1<-s1-alpha%*%disadv1-beta%*%adv1
  #u2<-s2-alpha%*%disadv2-beta%*%adv2
  udiff<-epsilon%*%(u2-u1)

  # Use the log-likelihood of the Bernouilli distribution, where p is
  # defined as the logistic transformation of a linear combination
  # of predictors, according to logit(p)=(x%*%beta)
  loglik <- sum(-y*log(1 + exp(-udiff)) - (1-y)*log(1 + exp(udiff)))
  return(-loglik)
}

##############################################################
###                 Step 2: Prepare the data               ###
##############################################################

df_sbj<-read.csv('./model/testdata_bbmle.csv',header=T)
fit <- mle2(logl, start = list(alpha = 0.2, beta=0.2, delta1=0.02,   delta2=0.02, delta3=0.02, epsilon=0),method="BFGS",data=df_sbj,skip.hessian=T)
```

Comment: how big is the test data set?  there are a lot of ways to post data online for free ...

Comment: Actually just a .txt file. The problem is that I don't have a web drive account. What way of uploading do you recommend?